# Create and update field Mongoose NodeJs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

```
{
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "5a4e5b1d09fb590058bfdf86"
        },
        "name": "ProjectStore",
        "imageURL": "none",
        "longitude": 0,
        "latitude": 0,
        "rating": 5,
        "leads": [
            {
                "customerId": "5a0c57db65a4931768716566",
                "customerName": "testuser",
                "interested": "testuser",
                "_id": {
                    "$oid": "5a4e5b5409fb590058bfdf88"
                }
            }
        ],
        "items": [
            {
                "name": "chat",
                "categoryID": "5a0c2d292235680012bd12c9",
                "semiCatID": "5a0c2d5f2235680012bd12cb",
                "_id": {
                    "$oid": "5a4e5b3009fb590058bfdf87"
                }
            }
        ],
        "__v": 2
    }
```

I added my DB log, I try to write query that will let me update/push information to "LeadStatus".

This varible should be inside each object in the "leads" array.

I have the keys for the main id "5a4e5b1d09fb590058bfdf86"
I have the second key for the specific lead "5a4e5b5409fb590058bfdf88"

I just dont know how to write the query, for now i got this.... and got error.

```
Store.update(
      { _id: req.body.store._id, 'leads._id': 'req.body.lead._id', },
      { $set: { 'leads.$.LeadStatus': 'open' }, },
      (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
          res.status(500)
          .json({ error: 'Unable to update leads.', });
        } else {
          res.status(200)
          .json(result);
        }
      }
    );
```

Please Help,
Thanks.

Comment: Get rid of quotes around req.body.lead._id and also you may need to cast the string value  ids as mongoose object id type.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want the updated doc returned (you can choose to not do so as well, switch option new to false). You have to assign an object the value that you're updating and provide all the fields within the subfield you're updating, otherwise it will remove everything else. That's why you have to do a findOne first:

```
return Store.findOne({ '_id': "5a4e5b1d09fb590058bfdf86" })
.then((store) => {
    if (!store) { // patient was not found for some reason
        throw new Error(`Store id was not found`);
    }
    const options = {
        new: true,
    };
    const updatedStore = Object.assign({}, store.toObject(), {
        leads: [
            {
                "leadStatus": "open",
                "customerId": "5a0c57db65a4931768716566",
                "customerName": "testuser",
                "interested": "testuser",
                "_id": {
                    "$oid": "5a4e5b5409fb590058bfdf88"
                }
            }
        ],
    });
    return Store.findOneAndUpdate(
        { '_id': req.body.store._id },
        { $set: updatedStore },
        options);
});
```

In case you're curious, you can build pre/virtual hooks off of findOneAndUpdate (no documentation for this), you won't lose anything from not using update.

Comment: Hi, i understood your answer but i dont think its can help me, the Leads array are going to raise every time, so i dont know what will be there.
Anyway you code give me some error:

"Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): CastError: Cast to embedded failed for value"